# Do posekim have special honorific titles like Rabbis (HaRav) or Gaonim (HaGaon) do?

Tags: minhag, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, honors

Many positions in Jewish life carry honorific titles with them. For instance, Rabbis are styled with HaRav before their name or Gaon (literally "genius") are styled with HaGaon. I'm curious to know whether there is such a title like the aforementioned ones for someone who is a posek?

EDIT: I wonder if "Posek HaDor" can be considered something like that.

Comment: this will be highly dependant on minhag

Comment: It's not one or the other. A posek can be both a HaRav and a HaGaon

Comment: @Dov Of course, but I'm asking if the position of a posek has a special title for itself that could be used for addressing a posek.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Any examples that you could direct me to for further research?

Comment: "Posek" and, outside of medieval Babylonia, "Gaon" are not official positions, let alone have regulations re titles.

Comment: @DoubleAA The posek can be an official position particularly in some communities. Gaon still has an *honorific title* - since even such positions can have one.

Comment: Indeed any community can make any position it wants with any name and any title and any function. If you are asking about a specific one, please define it explicitly.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was asking in a generalized sense - not for a particular community. I think this is clear enough.

Comment: But in the generalized sense there is no such official position.

Comment: @DoubleAA Generalized within the presumed context of the collection of these communities. Moreover, I'd argue there is.

Comment: @RabbiKaii What am I supposed to get from that link? It doesn't talk about posekim.

Comment: @RabbiKaii .....ok............... Thank you anyway, I appreciate it.

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe often used the term in a more extended form, "Posek Moreh Hora'ah. In this context, he emphasized that such an individual not only knew halacha in detail and correctly, but its proper application in specific, given circumstances as it applies to individuals. He would often contrast this with a Rav, who knows the halacha correctly. If I remember correctly, this same type of usage was also used by Rabbi Zalman Shimon Dworkin, A"H who was the Av Beit Din of the Beit Din HaOlami for Lubavitch, in the context of 'Who is a Rav?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such title among Ashkenazim. The title "Chacham" may imply that for Sefardim.

An Ashkenazi might be appointed to a position that requires the ability to pasken, such as a beis din, but that is a job description more than a title.